# Wordpress Civicrm tab won't open

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

Civicrm seems to install fine. However, When I click on the Civicrm tab from the admin panel, I get the error "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred." I check the log file and receive the below error but I have no idea what it means:

```
Dec 13 18:51:22  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => 
    [code] => 
)


Dec 13 18:51:22  [info] $backTrace = #0     /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381):         CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(307): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
#2 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#3 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#4 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1248): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#5 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#6 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#7 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#8 /home/matthe82/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#9 {main}
```

Comment: This is a good question, and you've provided all the right info!  Unfortunately, I've never seen anything like this so I can't give a good answer.  Can you check to make sure there's an `xml` directory inside your `civicrm/civicrm` folder? Are the permissions correct?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I found the easiest solution was to just reinstall the website from a previous backup and reinstall civicrm. All is working great now.